# Ansible nested variables with with_sequence loop

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

i'm trying to create multiple VMs by setting the number of machines as a variable then iterate over that number using with_sequence. The deal is that I want to manually assign static IP addresses to my VMs so I have to iterate with nested variables.

My main file:

```
- name: Create Azure VM
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
      - vault.yml
  pre_tasks:

   - set_fact:
        cluster: "testvm"

   - set_fact:
        subnetName: "default"

   - set_fact:
        instancesCount: 2

   - set_fact:
        IP1: "172.16.32.83"

   - set_fact:
        IP2: "172.16.32.84"

   - set_fact:
        vmSize: "Standard_DS1_v2"

   - set_fact:
        osDiskType: "Standard_LRS"

   - set_fact:
        dataDiskType: "Premium_LRS"

   - set_fact:
        diskSize: "4"

  roles:

   - azure
```

The snippet for the `azure` role used above where we have issues:

```
  - name: Create virtual network interface cards
    azure_rm_networkinterface:
      resource_group: "{{ envir }}-emp-{{ cluster }}"
      name: "{{ envir }}-emp-{{ cluster }}-nic-{{ item }}"
      virtual_network: "/subscriptions/{{ subscriptionId }}/resourceGroups/{{ vnetResourceGroup }}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{{ virtualNetworkName }}"
      subnet: "{{ subnetName }}"
      public_ip: no
      create_with_security_group: False
      ip_configurations:
        - name: ipconfig1
          primary: yes
          private_ip_address: "{{vars[IP].instancesCount}}" --->> here lies the question
          private_ip_allocation_method: Static
          primary: True
    with_sequence: "count={{ instancesCount }}"
```

How would we call the values of the `IP1` and `IP2` inside the loop under the `with_sequence` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try with something like this:

```
"{{ lookup('vars', 'IP{}'.format(instancesCount)) }}"
```